# Symfony with doctrine multible key

Tags: symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys

Sorry if my question is too basic, but I have a table and should link to foreign table with two primary key:

**Main table:**

```
class Articles
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="article_id", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private string $articleId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="manufacturer_id", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private string $manufacturerId = "0000000000";

   ...

}
```

**Forign table:**

```
class AssortmentArticle
{

   ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Articles::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="article_id")
     */
    private string $articleId;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Articles::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="manufacturer_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="assortment_id")
     */
    private int $manufacturerId;

   ...
```

But with two keys I cannot migrate to database. What is the correct way?

Comment: Have a look at this. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

Comment: Thank you. I know those page but there is no example with multiple key for ManyToOne